# Show that $\mathrm{Re}(z)\mathrm{Im}(z)$ is complex differentiable only on $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $f(z) = \mathrm{Re}(z)\mathrm{Im}(z)$ is complex differentiable only on $0$. Suppose we need to find $f'(z_0)$. When $z_0 = 0$ then $$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} {\dfrac{f(0+\Delta z) - f(0)}{\Delta z} = \lim_{\Delta z \to 0} {\dfrac {\mathrm{Re}(\Delta z)\mathrm{Im}(\Delta z)}{\mathrm{Re}(\Delta z)+i\mathrm{Im}(\Delta z)}}} = \lim_{\Delta z \to 0}{\dfrac{1}{1/\mathrm{Im}(\Delta z) + i/\mathrm{Re}(\Delta z)}} = 1/\infty = 0$$

But I can't show that the complex derivative doesn't exist on any other $z_0$. Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The book contains many typos. Maybe it had to be $|f(z)|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write real and imaginary parts $z=x+iy$ and  $\Delta z = h+ik$.

$$
\frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z} = \frac{(x+h)(y+k) - xy}{h+ik}
=\frac{xk+yh+hk}{h+ik}
$$
What is the limit of this as $(h,k) \to (0,0)$?  If that limit exists, then in particular we may take the limits in $h$ and $k$ separately...
$$
\lim_{k\to 0}\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{xk+yh+hk}{h+ik}\right) = \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{xk}{ik} = \lim_{k\to 0} (-ix) = -ix ,
\\
\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{xk+yh+hk}{h+ik}\right) =
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{yh}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} y = y .
$$
So, if the derivative exists at the point $x+iy$, we must have $y=-ix$.
A real number equal to a purely imaginary number?  Conclusion: $x=y=0$.

Comment: This is what sl99 said, in case you do not know the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  Or in case you do not assume differentiability at more than the single point $x+iy$, and cannot deduce "continuously differentiable".

Comment: Thank you! I was actually studying the chapter that comes right before the chapter about Cauchy-Riemann equations. Also, what a cool method of of assuming the limit exists and applying the repeated limits, I've never paid attention to this and now I wonder if there are any other interesting problems that could be solved this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try defining  z=x+iy  so that f(x+iy)=xy .
Then you can write u(x,y)=xy , v(x,y)=0 .
You can see that: $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(u\right)=x$ ,$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(u\right)=y$ , $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(v\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(v\right)=0$ on a general point.
So, notice that Cauchy Rieman equations:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(u\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(v\right)$$ $$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(u\right)=-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(v\right)$$
exists only on z=0.
[I related on that sen: A complex function f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) has a complex derivative f′(z) if and only if its real and imaginary part are continuously differentiable and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations
ux=vy,uy=−vx
In this case, the complex derivative of f(z) is equal to any of the following expressions:
f′(z)=ux+ivx=vy−iuy].

Comment: Thanks, just started learning about these equations